# R: optimize subsetting and dropping factor levels

Tags: r, optimization

I am optimizing R code that gets called many times and found that the following two commands consume the most time:

```
dataset <- dataset[which(dataset$responder==T),]

  for (i in 1:ncol(dataset))
    if (is.factor(dataset[,i]))
      dataset[,i] <- dataset[,i][drop=T]
```

I tried Googling to see if there is a way to optimize these, but did not find anything. Is there a way to improve these lines or is this simply as fast as it gets? Ideally a solution should not require compiling or make the code unreadable.

Comment: wouldn't `dataset[dataset$responder,]` be faster than `dataset[which(dataset$responder==T),]` ?

Comment: @BenBolker: Thank you for the suggestion. It seems which() is an extremely optimized function. Doing some simulations, I get mean 114 ms for which() and mean 110 ms for just using the logical vector directly. There is an improvement in median from 87 to 77. However, when using your suggestion the user has to be sure there are no NA in the dataset, as they will produce NA rows in the output.

Comment: @BenBolker: isTRUE is an abbreviation for identical(TRUE, x) and should not be used in this scenario as it will always return FALSE if the vector has length greater than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using vectorization, the code becomes slightly faster.

```
dataset <- droplevels(dataset[dataset$responder==T,])
```

**TEST**

```
library(microbenchmark)

# data
testdata=data.frame(type=c(rep("a", 5000), rep("b", 5000), rep("c",5000)), 
     responder=c(rep(TRUE, 4000), rep(FALSE,11000)))

# functions
orig <- function(){ ...code in question... }
vect <- function(){ ...code in answer... }

 microbenchmark(orig())
Unit: microseconds
   expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq      max neval
 orig() 638.27 654.929 793.7463 668.535 688.643 6650.592   100
 microbenchmark(vect())
Unit: microseconds
   expr     min       lq     mean  median     uq      max neval
 vect() 618.021 636.0365 768.6891 643.895 665.27 5122.989   100
```